# os.walk for loop is executing code with each iteration, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, iteration, os.walk

I'm trying to collect files in a list from a directory to create links for a web page, but when the "for" loop completes, it executes the append function with each iteration. So I'm getting the same data triplicated, I'm guessing for each part of the loop (root, subdir, and files) iteration. What am I doing wrong or how should I do this differently?

I'm pretty sure I've run this code or code like this before and not had the data triplicate so i'm at a loss as to why it's doing it now.

```py
    try:
        for root, subdir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
               for file in files:
                  drive, path_and_file = os.path.splitdrive(root)
                  parts = path_and_file.split("\\")
                  if parts[2] == "Lots":
                     lotPart = [parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], file]
                     iniLotParts.append(lotPart)

         gatherLots(iniLotParts)

    except Exception as e:
       print("type error: for gather data " + str(e))
       print(traceback.format_exc())
```

It seems it's going through my 'if parts[2] == "Lots":' loop multiple times. I'd expect it only to loop through it once.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. `gatherLots(iniLotParts)` needs to be at the same indentation as `for root` or `for file`.

Comment: Why should it loop it only once? It should go through it for each file in `files`.

Comment: Can you show an example of the file hierarchy, what you expect to get, and what you're getting instead?

Comment: @Barmar yes, it should go through for each file in file, but it's doing it three times. A simple directory structure would be...
TaxMaps
   Lots
      TWP1
        file1.pdf
        file2.pdf
      TWP2
         file1.pdf
         file2.pdf

Comment: What's happening is that the same filename exists in three different directories. `os.walk()` processes each directory, and the directory will be in `root`.

Comment: It won't make a difference in the results, but you should move the code that calculates `parts` and tests `parts[2] == "Lots"` outside the `for file in files:` loop, since it doesn't change for each file.

Comment: A good place to start would be logging `root`, `subdir` and `files` for every tuple `os.walk()` yields. That should go a long ways towards making it clear if the yielded values are surprising you, or the behavior of your code when processing those values is surprising you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out! As it turns out I didn't quit understand how using the a "for" loop with os.walk worked. I thought it stayed within the loop for all of the elements of the loop (i.e. root, subdir, & files).  So I collected my items within my list then made a function call out side of my loop when I thought all was collected.  What I found out was, that function call was made each time it looped through an element, specifically each sub-directory. So I changed up my code a bit based on some of the feedback I received and place my function calls more appropriately within the for loop. I also added an additional section for a different document I needed to collect.  What I finally ended up with is as follows:

```
def gatherData(rootdir):
    try:
        r=[]
        subdirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk(rootdir)]

        for subdir in subdirs:
            iniLotParts = []
            iniSecParts = []
            iniMuniParts = []
            drive, path_and_file = os.path.splitdrive(subdir)
            parts = path_and_file.split("\\")
            files = os.walk(subdir).next()[2]
            if (len(parts) == 4):
                if parts[2] == "Lots":                    
                    for file in files:
                        lotPart = [parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], file]
                        iniLotParts.append(lotPart)
                    gatherLots(iniLotParts)
                if parts[2] == "Section":
                    for file in files:
                        secPart = [parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], file]
                        iniSecParts.append(secPart)
                    gatherSecs(iniSecParts) 
    except Exception as e:
        print("type error: for gather data " + str(e))
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Thanks everyone that contributed!